# setting up methods with the Main.java file

Tags: java, static

Super new to Java
I have a main class that has the `public static void main (String args[]){}` call. I am only allowed to use the Scanner class from the Main class. I'm trying to get up my code to be as reusable as possible. I have a set of instructions created in a different class. To access these instructions I'm doing this.

```
public static void main (String args[]){
    Main main = new Main();
    main.showInstructions();
}
```

which allows me to call this function

```
void showInstructions(){
    instructions.welcome();
}
```

And above the static main call, I have my variables

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
// create a new instructions
Instructions instructions = new Instructions();
```

Is doing this type of thing `Main main = new Main();` good practice? My thought process is that I can use the method `instructions()` over and over if I need to.
It seems without doing something like that everything has to be static in the Main java class.

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally wrong with you've done but it's not clear what question you are asking.  Can you clarify?  For example, if you've considered different options and you're not sure which is better, can you show those options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. In fact, your `main` should generally be a one-liner that creates an instance (usually of the `Main` class) and invokes an instance method on that, passing `args` to either the constructor or that method, but only if you care about the args. You're essentially doing that (you can one-liner it: `new Main().showInstructions();` works fine, but if `showInstructions()` doesn't just show the instructions but also asks for feedback and in general runs the entire app, `showInstructions` is not a good name. `mainLoop` is an option, as is `menu()`, if it's the kind of setup where you ask the user to enter an option.

The reason is `static`: `static` is a bit complicated. When you fully understand what it does but you have no experience with programming and your brain is mostly thinking about the various (generally extremely simple) 'java 101' homework exercises, you tend to think `static` is absolutely amazing and everything should be `static` - whereas the actual behaviour of programmers is that `static` is inappropriate for just about everything except stateless utility methods, and even then its a dubious idea – this isn't contentious: Just about every programmer considers static state a serious problem.

As a consequence, better to just not use `static`. Your `main` method has to be, but, 'get out' ASAP: instantiate the class, invoke a instance (non-`static`) method, and that's it. Other than `main` itself, no `static` anywhere, that's the right approach.